# Checking input text and upload file in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to check if the user put something in my textarea or if he added an image. How can I do it in codeigniter?

My scenario is, he can post both text and image or text only or image only but either one of it must not be empty.

But when I tried it, it doesn't work. I always get error that is both of 2 is empty even though I added an image.

variable:

textarea = body

file = image_upload

```
    if ($_POST) {
        if (empty($_POST['body']) == true && !isset($_POST['image_upload']))
        {
            //no message & image
            header("location:". $_POST['base_url'] . '?error_post');
        }
        elseif(empty($_POST['body']) == false && !isset($_POST['image_upload']))
        {
            //message only
        }
        elseif (empty($_POST['body']) == true && isset($_POST['image_upload']) == true) {
                //image only
                $config['upload_path'] = './public/uploads/';
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
                $config['max_size'] = '100';
                $config['max_width']  = '1024';
                $config['max_height']  = '768';

                $this->load->library('upload', $config);

                if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
                {
                    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

                    //$this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
                    var_dump($error);
                    die();
                }
                else
                {
                    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

                    //$this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
                    var_dump($data);
                    die();
                }
        }
        else{
            //both message & image
            var_dump($_POST);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

form_validation can help you, https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html

try something like this :

```
<?php
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('body','body','required');

            $config['upload_path'] = './public/uploads/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
            $config['max_size'] = '100';
            $config['max_width']  = '1024';
            $config['max_height']  = '768';

            $this->upload->initialize($config);
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);


        if($this->form_validation->run())
        {


                $image_data = $this->upload->data();
                $image_name = $image_data['file_name'];

                $data = array(
                    'image_upload'=>$image_name,
                    'body'=>$this->input->post('body')
                );

                $this->MyModel->create($data);


                redirect('...');


        }else{


            if(!$this->upload->do_upload('image_upload'))
            {
                redirect('...');
            }
            else
            {
                $image_data = $this->upload->data();
                $image_name = $image_data['file_name'];

                $data = array(
                    'image_upload'=>$image_name
                );

                $this->MyModel->create($data);


                redirect('...');
            }

        }
```

Comment: Thanks! I am going to try this now. I'll be back later.

Comment: It's not working.. I'm always redirected though I added `body` and `image`.